# SharePoint Online: How can you hide the footer bar on a document preview when I embed an Excel spreadsheet onto a page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, modern-pages

It seems to hide when I use the Chrome developer tools, but when I do the same thing with the modern script editor, nothing changes.  Anyone have any luck hiding this bar?  If you ask me what I've tried...a lot of things.  :|

[image]

```
.ewa-embed-ltr .ewa-embed-buttons {
  display: none;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JavaScript to hide the bar, then it is probably an order of execution problem e.g. your JS attempts to hide the bar before it has been loaded.

**Edit:** The question has been edited to show that CSS is being used to hide the element rather than JS, so I've had a second look.

The File Viewer web part showing the Excel file is loaded in an iframe. You cannot apply styles to HTML loaded inside an iframe using CSS only.

This would be an unsupported customisation however, please see the list of supported customisations for modern SharePoint pages:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages#supported-customizations-for-modern-pages